# Install Ming on WebFaction

Tags: python, webfaction

I'm trying to install the [Ming](https://github.com/libming/libming) SWF creation library from source on WebFaction. After untarring it, I ran `./configure --prefix=$HOME -enable--python` and then ran `make install`. It seemed to install fine, but when I do a `import ming` from within Python it gives me an import error. These steps worked for me on my local machine. I was hoping someone could help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the folder containing the library on Python's search path?

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I also posted this on the webfaction forum, and got it to work. In case anyone else runs into this problem: http://community.webfaction.com/questions/3353/install-ming-from-source